# angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker and masked input

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I am taking my first steps in Angular & hope i am in the correct place to find an answer to my question/issue.
If not, please point me in the right direction.

I am using the angular UI bootstrap popup datepicker like the example here : 
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

When i combine this with the uiMask Directive ( http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/) the values in the input get scrambled when i pick a date.

I suspect because of the difference in type on the angular model : datepicker wants JS Date object/ ui.mask wants (masked) string.

When the picked date gets formatted/parsed by uiMask, it goes wrong :-/

Is what i am trying to do even possible ?

kind regards, Tom.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in knowing the answer.  Here is example of combining the ui-mask with the datepicker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/88ax7pkiEhsD5b74q3Bf?p=preview

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ui-mask="99/99/9999" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
```